# Transposing two digits of a four-digit number gives a number six-times bigger. What's the original number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we transpose two digits in a four-digit number, we will get a (four-digit) number six times bigger than the original. What was the original number?

Comment: which two digits?

Answer (score 2):

Since the number must be six times as big, the first digit is a likely candidate to be swapped, holding an initial value of $1$. Assuming the last digit is not swapped, this digit must equal $4$ or $6$ in order for the multiplied number to again end with the same digit. This leaves a limited search space, and we indeed find:

$$6 \cdot 1386 = 8316$$